# Localization for "Delete" label of .onDelete modifier (SwiftUI/Lists)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

When I use the `.onDelete` modifier in a SwiftUI list (in particular in an embedded `ForEach` statement) there's added an appropriate red button when you slide from the right to the left as expected. My question is about the label of this button: it says "Delete" - is there any way to localize this label in case the app is supposed to support other languages than English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already localised. You just need to add support for corresponding language to your application

[image: demo1]

and when system will have that language set preferred...

[image: demo2]

... the button will be localised correspondingly

[image: demo3]

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had just switched the language in the scheme to test this but not yet added the according language support. Now it works!